# USB wlan1 Hotspot stops working when eth0 cable is plugged in

Tags: routing, raspberry

I setup successfully an USB `wlan1` as AP via `hostapd`, and `isc-dhcpd` (it listens only to `wlan1`-interface) on a Raspberry 4 (using Raspbian). Regardless if `wlan0` (the onboard WIFI) is connected to a WAN hotspot, `wlan1` Clients can ping that `wlan1` interface. IP Forwarding/masquerade works, and if `wlan0` is connected to WAN AP, `wlan1` clients also have internet access. Perfect!

But in the moment i plug-in `eth0`, `wlan1` clients can still connect to that AP (Status `connected`), but can NOT PING that `wlan1` interface anymore (and no WAN access anymore).
That's weird! The DHCP Server pushed the same valid IP's to the client as before, and static IP of `wlan1` also stays the same (`eth0` and `wlan1` have static IP). `wlan1` can be pinged locally from the rapsberry (but not from an external client).

When i un-plug `eth0`, it work's again.

What's going wrong and why i canot even ping that interface anymore?

sysctl IPv4 forwarding is enabled.

```
...
$ ip link
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
4: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
...
```

```
$ ip addr
...
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:84:db:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.8.0.2/8 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:84:db:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:f3:c1:23:2d:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.8.5.1/8 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...
```

```
$nft list ruleset
...
table ip nat {
        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                masquerade
        }
}
...
```

```
$ cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf 
interface=wlan1
#If this fails, try rt1871xdrv a
#driver=nl80211
# Name of the new network: best use the hostname
ssid=xxx

# Pick a channel not already in use
channel=1
# Change to b for older devices?
hw_mode=g
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=3
# Disable this to insure the AP is visible:
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=xxx
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

#bridge=br0 # no bridge! We're using routing
country_code=JP
```

```
cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf 
...
interface eth0
static ip_address=10.8.0.2/8
static routers=10.8.0.1
static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1

interface wlan1
static ip_address=10.8.5.1/8
nohook wpa_supplicant
static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1

interface wlan0
static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1
```

```
cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
...
authoritative;

subnet 10.8.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.8.5.201 10.8.5.250;
  option broadcast-address 10.8.5.255;
  option routers 10.8.5.1;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
  option domain-name "local";
  option domain-name-servers 10.8.5.1;
}

host ares {
  hardware ethernet 04:ea:56:ae:58:03;
  fixed-address 10.8.5.20;
}
```

```
$ ipconfig # on Windows 11 Client
...
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 04-EA-56-AE-58-03
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9300:7ccf:3e03:eaf9%17(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.5.20(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, 16 December 2022 22:56:38
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, 16 December 2022 23:06:37
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.5.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.5.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 168094294
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-26-1E-05-25-48-2A-E3-3A-C9-F0
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.5.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IP addresses are:

- 10.8.0.2/8 for `wlan1`
- 10.8.5.1/8 for `eth0`

Those are in the *same* subnet. 10.0.0.0/8 covers everything from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255.

Yet, on your DHCP scope, the netmask is suddenly /24.

The general rule is that if you want to send traffic within a subnet, you need a switch (bridge), while you need a router to send traffic between subnets. When your machine gets a packet from one of your connected clients - which believe 10.8.5.0/24 is a subnet, it doesn't understand what to do with it, as it's addressed to a host in the same subnet as the originator.

You probably want /24 defined everywhere, so replace the netmask for `eth0` and `wlan1` with /24, not /8.

As to observed behavior: routes carry a weight. Faster interfaces float to the top. Your machine believes `wlan1` and `eth0` both point to the same destination. Thus, it sends the packet over the *best* interface (lowest weight in the routing table), which is the wired Ethernet interface. If it was properly configured with separate subnets, it'll work just fine.

Comment: That's it! Yea, i accidentally mixed-up `/8` with `/24`. After changing to `/24`, the AP is pingable. But now I have another problem: The Clients do not have WAN access anymore (but the server has)

Comment: Your wan router doesn't have a valid route to your clients behind the pi. And you should probably accept the answer so we avoid having the question popping up every few months...